# Grafana delaying the data by 5 hours when imported from MySql

Tags: mysql, plot, mysql-workbench, grafana

I am trying to understand why my grafana is showing the data with timestamp-5 hrs with data remaining the same. I don't know why. Presently I am in EST.

Here is the MySql database connection, and I defined no timezone.
[image]

But presently the time now at my location is 21:20 but the grafana plot is showing data by delaying the time by 5 hours exactly with same data but I don't know why the time is delayed by 5 hrs. I appreciate your help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data in the DB are in EST timezone. Insert them with UTC timezone and all your Grafana time zones issues will be gone.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Can you please elaborate on how to insert the UTC timezone? You mean, in the timezone session on the grafana database page, do I have to insert something like this "UTC-05:00"?